# How do I get the last X number of rows from a forms-sheets linked sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-apps

This is my first time asking a question so I apologize in advance for any lack of information,

I'm working on a timesheet for a friends company, the employees are labourers who wouldn't be reliable with a manual clock in/clock out app, they prefer a weekly submission of hours. So I have a basic google forms set up, and every week I want to display the last X (No. of employees) submissions in a separate sheet for the MD and accountant.

[Format they come in from FORMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XO3Gy.png)
[Desired sheet + format to show MD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghsKG.png)

Is it possible to do this using google apps script? As I have a trigger script to clear this table every Tuesday, so ideally I would like a google apps script with a trigger to pull the last X rows on a Wednesday eve for the MD to approve and send to the accountant.

I was thinking of finding the last row on the forms response sheet, then pulling all other responses with the same date on the timestamp? So it would just be that weeks responses. I could have a simple count function for the responses then, so he would know if anyone hasn't submitted their hours.

Thanks in advance for any and all help and advice!

Tom

Answer (score 0):

```
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() -  x + 1, 1, x, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues()
```